# jQuery IP address validation failed

Tags: jquery, regex

Below is the code snippet where I have written the code to have the IP address masked and validate it using jQuery. But, I am getting error message for valid IP addresses (like 222.222.222.222). Can someone please help?

```
            //Validate the form
            $('#form').validate({
                rules: {
                    ip: {
                        required: true,
                        IP4Checker: true
                    },
                    subnet: {
                        required: true,
                        IP4Checker: true
                    },
                    gateway: {
                        required: true,
                        IP4Checker: true
                    },
                    dns1: {
                        required: true,
                        IP4Checker: true
                    },
                    dns2: {
                        required: true,
                        IP4Checker: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    ip: "Please enter a valid IP Address",
                    subnet: "Please enter a valid Subnet Mask Address",
                    gateway: "Please enter a valid Gateway Address",
                    dns1: "Please enter a valid DNS1 Address",
                    dns2: "Please enter a valid DNS2 Address"
                }
            });

            //Validate the IP addresses
            $(function() {
                $.validator.addMethod('IP4Checker', function(value) {
                    var ip = "^(?:(?:25[0-5]2[0-4][0-9][01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}" +
                        "(?:25[0-5]2[0-4][0-9][01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$";
                    return value.match(ip);
                });
            });

            //Set mask for IP address fields
            $(".ip").mask("999 . 999 . 999 . 999");

            //Store numbers in hidden field
            $(".ip").blur(function () {

                //Create char array from phone number field
                var charArray = $(this).val().split("");

                var num = "";

                //taking the input
                $.each(charArray, function(index, value) {
                    num = num + value;
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regex is missing its | characters ie.

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

Also note you could shorten this to

```
\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b
```

If you dont need to check it is a valid ip address between 0-255

also any \ needs to be escaped itself so it will be \

[reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html)

**UPDATE**

OP showed fiddle and hadnt read above line also mask had spaces either side of the . so the regex was never valid as the mask added the spaces.

[fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K9b9R/5/)

Comment: I tried it but it dint work, sorry. I tried couple of other regular expressions too, but it dint work too.
Please refer to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K9b9R/4/

Comment: Wow, that weird. I had thought of that and removed those spaces too. But I think I was not using this regex that time. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: 94.156.240.100 dont work due as your regex is demanding 3 digits for each, 123.123.123.400 does work in the fiddle even tho it shouldnt (but as i said the shorter regex will not check for 0-255

Comment: What is the fix for 123.123.123.400 ?

Comment: I am using the longer version of regex that you provided as a fix for 123.123.123.400. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your function with

```
//IP V4

jQuery.validator.addMethod("IP4Checker", function(value, element, param) {
return this.optional(element) || /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)$/i.test(value);



//IP V6

jQuery.validator.addMethod("IP6Checker", function(value, element, param) {
return this.optional(element) || /^((([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}:([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:)?[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}:([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}:([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}:([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,4}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}((\b((25[0-5])|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(\d{1,2}))\b)\.){3}(\b((25[0-5])|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(\d{1,2}))\b))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,5}:((\b((25[0-5])|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(\d{1,2}))\b)\.){3}(\b((25[0-5])|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(\d{1,2}))\b))|(::([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,5}((\b((25[0-5])|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(\d{1,2}))\b)\.){3}(\b((25[0-5])|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(\d{1,2}))\b))|([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}::([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(::([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1,7}:))$/i.test(value);
});
```